# How can I create a column that is a 0-9 hash of text in another column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hash

Our application has the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]     NVARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL,
    [EnglishHash] AS (CONVERT([bigint],hashbytes('md5',[English])%(5)+(5))) PERSISTED,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC)
);
```

The intention was for the EnglishHash column to be a value of either 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, or 9

However it's only giving values: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, or 9

Can anyone help to explain how I can modify this so it gives values 0-9 inclusive?

Note that I tried out the suggestion by Sandip. This gives me a distribution but over 11,000 records the distribution is not what I expected:

```
0   593
9   652
3   1324
6   1253
7   1293
1   1932
4   1325
5   1282
2   1295
8   635
```

Comment: just curious,In what circumtances i create such computed columns.any example,purpose ?you can even use round 
declare @i nvarchar(250)='d'
select abs( round(CONVERT([bigint],hashbytes('md5',@i)),1)%(5))

Comment: Can you please show me your data in table

Comment: Now that you've added a requirement that the statistical distribution must be "what I expected", what is the distribution of `[English]` values? There is no indication that they are unique.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your results only allow you to have 9 distinct values because you are taking the modulus of 5.  Look at the below results.  if you were to continue taking the modulus, you'll see it cannot be any integer greater than 4 and no less than -4 (this is before adding the last +5). It's just going to start looping.  Instead why don't you take modulus of 10 of the absolute value of the bigint value of the binary hash.

```
SELECT 0%5
    , 1%5
    , 2%5
    , 3%5
    , 4%5
    , 5%5
    , 6%5

SELECT 0%5
    , -1%5
    , -2%5
    , -3%5
    , -4%5
    , -5%5
    , -6%5
```

Try using this instead

```
ABS(CONVERT(bigint, HASHBYTES('md5',[English])))%10
```

Here's a nice example using the system error messages for some random text.

```
SELECT ABS(CONVERT(bigint, HASHBYTES('md5',[text])))%10 AS 'Result'
    , COUNT(*) AS 'Distribution'
from sys.messages
GROUP BY ABS(CONVERT(bigint, HASHBYTES('md5',[text])))%10
ORDER BY ABS(CONVERT(bigint, HASHBYTES('md5',[text])))%10
```

Results:

```
Result  Distribution
0   25326
1   25218
2   25115
3   25322
4   25167
5   25322
6   25278
7   25119
8   25139
9   25158
```

Comment: Thanks,  Can you give me an example of how I should change the line so it would allow me to pick between 0 and 9.

Comment: @alan i messed up an order of operations thing.  Make sure you have the same value as in my edited post

Comment: I tested this out.  But still only see 9 different hash values which are: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or 9.   I need ten hash values from 0-9

Comment: Check again, this answer is right. You can test it at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1ca29/15)

Comment: No need to `convert`, just `Abs( HashBytes( 'md5', [English] ) % 10 )`. The resulting value may not have an ideal statistical distribution, but that doesn't seem to be a requirement.

Comment: @Alan Can you show me the formula you're using?  The answer I posted gives all 10 different values...  I don't understand the problem you're having with it.  Try the following: `SELECT ABS(CONVERT(bigint, HASHBYTES('md5',[text])))%10 AS 'Result'
 , COUNT(*) AS 'Distribution'
from sys.messages
GROUP BY ABS(CONVERT(bigint, HASHBYTES('md5',[text])))%10
ORDER BY ABS(CONVERT(bigint, HASHBYTES('md5',[text])))%10`

Answer (score 1):

try below query, it gives me different hash value as your requirement:

```
--C=0
--B=1
--F=2
--t=3
--D=4
--S=5
--G=6
--A=7
--j=8
--P=9

DECLARE @myText VARCHAR='A'
SELECT ABS((HashBytes( 'md5', @myText ) %9)-1)
```